# How do I retrieve the address of the client that connects to my WCF service and stores it?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing a WCF duplex service that allows a server and a winform app client to connect to it. The server will be pushing a post to the service and the service will then send the post to the winform app client. In order to do this, I need to be able to differentiate the address of each client in order for me to choose which client do I push the data to.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question is just for me to use a publish/subscribe service.